# Is it possible to specify a custom CDN for ActiveStorage?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cdn, rails-activestorage

I am running a Ruby on Rails website and am currently using Rails' ActiveStorage to store my images and videos.

I am using a AWS based space for storage (DigitalOcean) and they recently rolled out support for custom CDN support. Meaning, instead of referencing `my-space.nyc3.digitalocean.com`, I would reference `assets.akinyele.ca`.

Everything has been setup on my DigicalOcean dashboard. But I was wondering if I could use `assets.akinyele.ca` on ActiveStorage instead.

I have tried not specifying a `bucket` that failed automatically because it looks like the ActiveStorage API requires that field, and uses it to build the space storage service's URL. I also tried specifying the `endpoint` to `assets.akinyele.ca`, but that gave me `my-space.assets.akinyele.ca`.

This is what a part of config looks like:

```
# config/storage.yml
local: #
development: #

# This is what I need to replace, and this is was I am using right now.
amazon:
  service: S3
  access_key_id: <%= ENV["TANOSHIMU_SPACE_ACCESS_KEY_ID"] %>
  secret_access_key: <%= ENV["TANOSHIMU_SPACE_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"] %>
  region: nyc3
  bucket: my space
  endpoint: 'https://nyc3.digitaloceanspaces.com'
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You can try to override `url` method for `ActiveStorage::Service::S3Service`

P.S. Use `bucket: ''` in your `config/storage.yml`

Comment: Thank you. I will give it a try and let you know how it goes.

Comment: I was able to completely override the URL, however, since my files are protected, they need a signed URL. I am getting a `SignatureDoesNotMatch` when replacing the digicalocean url with my CDN. Do you know if this is fixable?